# How to search with regexp within blocks?

Tags: python, regex

I have a long file that is composed of many blocks like this:

```
x=0
abc 20    
def 76   
ghi 11

x=1
def 45
ghi 32

x=2
jkl 56
mno 76
abc 134

.
.
.

x=393
xyz 21
abc 9

x=394
ghi 43
def 166
xyz 25
```

I need the regular expression (for python) to get this output:

```
return_list = [20,'x',134,...,9,'x']
```

(so matches for abc and x should be assigned to the same group)

So I need to look in each block if abc is available, if it is match integer after abc, if not match the 'x' at the beginning.
Block length (lines) are different for each block.

I tried that regexp: `(?ms)(?=x=\d).*?(?=\n\n)`

That matches all blocks separately.
I now need the extension to search for abc in the individual blocks and return the x if not present.

I have tried many things but since I am a beginner I can not find a solution. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does every block always begin with an x?

Comment: yes, every block always starts with an x.

Comment: Do you want the result to have a literal `'x'` in there, or do you mean that it should have the value of `x` in those positions, i.e. `[20, 1, 134, ..., 9, 394]`?

Comment: @Grismar I want the literal 'x'. So I can use it in the further course of my code to find the indexes of the places where there is no value.

Comment: With python default regex and no grouping e.g. [`(?<=^abc )\d+|^x(?==(?!(?:.+\n)*abc))`](https://regex101.com/r/2ubyki/1) but this one with two groups would be better to read: [`(?:^.+\n)*abc (\d+)|^(x)(?==)`](https://regex101.com/r/L3XHSt/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble very sneaky use of the `x` in the input text! I like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want with a single regex, by changing your regex to terminate at either `abc = \d+` or `\n\n` or `\Z` (to allow a match of the last group at the end of the string - this is required for your sample data as it doesn't finish with `\n\n`).

```
(?ms)(?=x=\d).*?(?:abc (\d+)|\n\n|\Z)
```

If `abc = \d+` is present in the block, the digits will be captured in group 1, otherwise it will be empty. You can then use this fact to substitute the value with an `'x'`:

```py
res = [m.group(1) or 'x' for m in re.finditer(r'(?ms)(?=x=\d).*?(?:abc (\d+)|\n\n|\Z)', data)]
```

Output:

```
['20', 'x', '134', '9', 'x']
```

Note if you want integers rather than strings you can modify the code slightly:

```
res = [int(m.group(1)) if m.group(1) else 'x' for m in re.finditer(r'(?ms)(?=x=\d).*?(?:abc (\d+)|\n\n|\Z)', data)]
```

Output:

```
[20, 'x', 134, 9, 'x']
```

Comment: The example output provided makes it look like the goal is for the numbers matched to also be converted to actual integers, but that's simple enough to fix. Slick!

Comment: @CalebKeller yeah, I've added code in case that is indeed the desired approach. I was originally going to post an answer like yours but you beat me to it so I had to come up with a different approach!

Comment: All solutions are good, but this solution was the best fit for my use case.
It helped me a lot and I have learned a lot.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you can use [PyPI regex,](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) this would be a good use for the PCRE [`\K` reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) feature.

```
matches = regex.findall(r"(?m)^x(?:=(?>.+\n)*?abc \K\d+)?\b", s)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5Nbdng/1) or the [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##RY5RDoIwDIbfd4pmT0MNcQw1miAHMN6gMUEZgkIhgwf08rgxjU2TNn//fm33GsqW1DRVTdeaAYy@6xGy3jaM9ZCA4GOyRsquN4jWYAMp1wXstnN7LyuQEglpTKSfxBsvq8jLtnDmFoE/njVstkgNtRbgoVLFzhf@0q2ovbLl9YZIetP@p8d/mL0xH5ydPGCsyYZbqd3PRodFRXlW18LwyyjSQyLSY7hEChap4@EJ82WQ4pWvoF85/9kCOlPRIL6YYJo@)

The `x` gets always matched at `^` line-start while the whole group after it is *optional*. If the optional part matches, the new match after `abc`  will just reset before the `\K\d+` digits (and drop previous).

Comment: Very nice and well explained answer, thanks for sharing. Could you please share the link OR more info on what is Pypi regex? Thank you

Comment: Although this is cool, it only works because OP wanted `'x'` as their "no match" value. If they had wanted `None` or `0` or some other value, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Nick I think it's efficient and useful whenever there is an optional part *after* a match that is wanted to reset (overwrite) a previous. As long as the "no match" value comes before, I can't see why this would not work. :) @RavinderSingh13 Thank you! Yes, there is [a link on "PyPI"](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that leads to the project page. It's an alternative and more powerful regex module for Python that adds some features from PCRE and #C.

Comment: @bobblebubble my point is that if the "no match" value doesn't exist in the input text, this strategy won't work. It's great for this particular question though.

Comment: When I import regexp (python 3.7) I always get this error:
unknown extension ?> at position 11

Comment: @Fox-MSVI Have you seen [the Python demo](https://tio.run/##RY5RDoIwDIbfd4pmT0MNcQw1miAHMN6gMUEZgkIhgwf08rgxjU2TNn//fm33GsqW1DRVTdeaAYy@6xGy3jaM9ZCA4GOyRsquN4jWYAMp1wXstnN7LyuQEglpTKSfxBsvq8jLtnDmFoE/njVstkgNtRbgoVLFzhf@0q2ovbLl9YZIetP@p8d/mL0xH5ydPGCsyYZbqd3PRodFRXlW18LwyyjSQyLSY7hEChap4@EJ82WQ4pWvoF85/9kCOlPRIL6YYJo@) that I provided in the answer? It's not regex**p** but `import regex` or in the demo `import regex as re`.[Here is a guide](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-install-regex-in-python/) for installation.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank you also for this great solution.
In principle even the solution I searched for, however I am limited as far as the execution environment is concerned. It does not allow me to install additional via pip install.
However, I must point out this solution as the most efficient solution (with the fewest steps and is therefore the fastest processed, which is quite relevant for my big file sizes).

Comment: @Fox-MSVI You're welcome, glad you noticed it is efficient! Maybe you can use it once. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```py
def processBlocks(inputString):
    # Break the string into blocks
    blocks = re.findall(r"(?s)(?:x=[0-9]+)(?:.(?!x=))*", inputString)
    result = []

    for block in blocks:
        # Check for "abc" followed by a number in this block
        number = re.search(r"abc ([0-9]+)", block)

        # If it's found, add it to the result. Otherwise, add "x".
        if number:
            result.append(int(number[1])) # Convert to actual int too.
        else:
            result.append("x")
    return result
```

Instead of trying to do everything in a single regex (although it is likely possible), it is much easier and more readable to break this into two steps: first we use a regex to break the string down into each block, then we look in the block to see if "abc" followed by a number is in it. If we find a number, we add it to the result list. Otherwise, we just append the literal value "x".

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
with open('input_file') as f:
    s = f.read()

m = re.findall(r'(?ms)^x(?==\d+\n(?!(?:\w+ \d+\n)*^abc))|(?<=^abc )\d+', s)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
['20', 'x', '134', '9', 'x']
```

- `^x(?==\d+\n(?!(?:\w+ \d+\n)*^abc))` matches `x` if it is followed by
  a `=` character and a number, but not followed by a string `abc`
  within the block.
- if the regex above does not match, `(?<=^abc )\d+`, a number preceded
  by a string `abc` , is used as an alternative.

Comment: What if OP wanted `'y'` or `None` instead of `'x'`?

Answer (score 2):

You might also use a single capture group with an alternation, first matching all lines that start with a non whitespace char and then backtrack to the first occurrence of abc followed by a digit, or x preceded by a digit

```
^(?:\S.*\n)*.*((?<=^abc )\d+|x(?==\d+$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7BL7ud/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eEnSDS)

Comment: Very nice idea 4th bird! Was trying to achieve this too using same group but gave up. :-D